# Backbone listen to custom collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

```
// build a collection of players with this team ID
this.collection = new PlayersCollection(App.data.players.where({team_id: this.model.id}));
```

When I do this it renders `this.collection = App.data.players;` it has to do with the collection being a new collection, how do I listen to a new collection?

With marionette I am passing a collection of players into a collection of teams with collectionViews, compositeViews, and itemViews.

*Teams collectionView > Team compositeView > Player itemView*

Inside the team compositeView I define `this.collection` as a new PlayersCollection that matches the particular teams ID. This renders perfect, but adding a new player I can't get the view to re-render without refreshing the page.

```
addPlayer: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $newPlayer = this.$el.find('input.player_name');

    var Player = {
        player_name : $newPlayer.val(), 
        team_id     : this.model.id
    }

    App.data.players.create(Player);
    $newPlayer.val('');

},
```

Here is a majority of the code. I am trying to add/create a new player and update the view with `listenTo` but since this is not a traditional way to define the collection it seems I have to find a way to bind it?

**Teams.js**:

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
    playerView = require('./player'),
    PlayersCollection = require('../../collections/players');

var teamView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    events: {
        'submit #AddPlayer': 'addPlayer'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        // anytime something within this specific team changes, render
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

        // build a collection of players with this team ID
        this.collection = new PlayersCollection(App.data.players.where({team_id: this.model.id}));

    },
    addPlayer: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $newPlayer = this.$el.find('input.player_name');

        var Player = {
            player_name : $newPlayer.val(), 
            team_id     : this.model.id
        }

        App.data.players.create(Player);
        $newPlayer.val('');

    },
    itemView: playerView,
    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
        collectionView.$('.the-players').append(itemView.el);
    }
});

module.exports = CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },
    itemView: teamView
});
```

**Players.js**:

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette');

module.exports = playerView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    className: 'players-wrap row',
    template: require('../../../templates/teams/player.hbs'),
    events: {
        'mouseenter .player-image': 'playerOn',
        'mouseleave .player-image': 'playerOff',
        'click .player-image': 'playerClicked',
        'keydown': 'on_keypress',
        'click .one-point': 'onePoint',
        'click .two-point': 'twoPoint',
        'click .three-point': 'threePoint'
    },
    initialize:function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'on_keypress');
        $(document).bind('keydown', this.on_keypress);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.$el.attr('data-player', this.model.get('player_name').replace(/\s+/g,"_").toLowerCase());
        window.play = this.model;
    },
    playerOn:function(e) {
        this.$el.addClass('hover');
        this.findPlayer(this.model.get('player_name'), 'add');      
    },
    playerOff:function() {
        this.$el.removeClass('hover');
        this.findPlayer(this.model.get('player_name'), 'remove');
    },
    playerClicked:function() {
        this.$el.toggleClass('hover-clicked');
        this.findPlayer(this.model.get('player_name'), 'toggle'); 
    },
    findPlayer:function(name, action) {
        var player = $('.data-wrap .player-data[data-player='+ name.replace(/\s+/g,"_").toLowerCase() +']');
        if(action === 'toggle') { player.toggleClass('show-confirmed-clicked') }
        if(action === 'add')    { player.addClass('show-player-data') }
        if(action === 'remove') { player.removeClass('show-player-data') }
    },
    onePoint:function(e) {
        var addStat = parseInt(this.model.get('points')) + 1;        
        this.model.set('points', addStat);
        this.model.save();
    },
    twoPoint:function(e) {
        var addStat = parseInt(this.model.get('points')) + 2;        
        this.model.set('points', addStat);
        this.model.save();
    },
    threePoint:function(e) {
        var addStat = parseInt(this.model.get('points')) + 3;        
        this.model.set('points', addStat);
        this.model.save();
    },
    on_keypress:function(e) {
        this.keyStat(e, 49, 'points', 1);   // 1 point
        this.keyStat(e, 50, 'points', 2);   // 2 points
        this.keyStat(e, 51, 'points', 3);   // 3 points
        this.keyStat(e, 82, 'rebounds', 1); // R rebounds
        this.keyStat(e, 83, 'steals', 1); // S steals
    },
    keyStat:function(e, keyVal, stat, number) {
        if(e.keyCode == keyVal && !e.ctrlKey) { 
            if(this.$el.hasClass('hover')) {
                var addStat = parseInt(this.model.get(stat)) + number;        
                this.model.set(stat, addStat);
                this.model.save();
            }
        }
    },
    templateHelpers:function(){
        return {
            name_format: this.model.get('player_name').replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase()
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the place where you adding your new model to the CompositeView's collection? I found only `App.data.players.create(Player);` which is not the collection of CompositeView.

If `App.data.players` is another Backbone.Collection which you need to keep in sync with the remote server and because of that you are using `create` to persist it to the server, then change addPlayer like this:

```
addPlayer: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $newPlayer = this.$('input.player_name');

    var Player = {
        player_name : $newPlayer.val(), 
        team_id     : this.model.id
    }

    var newPlayer = App.data.players.create(Player);
    this.collection.add(newPlayer);
    $newPlayer.val('');

},
```

`CompositeView` will catch the "add" event of collection and will append new itemView.
Please try and let me know if it helps.

**Just a note:** After review of your code I found that `appendHtml` in Teams.js can be removed with `itemViewContainer` property with value of `.the-players` which will improve performance of rendering.

Comment: Yeah so it was a nested collection, then I took players out of the team object and made the players collection global, that is most likely why it does not fire, due to it being global. I need to pass it into the view. You're right, I need to figure out how I can do that to a composite view

Comment: Worked well, thanks man. I wish I would have thought of that lol. Thank's for the wonderful people here.

Comment: I am reading about `itemViewContainer` is it just a function. How should I swap it for `appendHtml`

Comment: Actually it's a property of `CompositeView` which, if its setted, will point to the container where `ItemViews` of collection's models will be rendered. Read more [here](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.8.8/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-itemviewcontainer).

Comment: Yeah I just removed `appendHtml` and added this `itemViewContainer: '.the-players',` thanks man it worked good and seemed to have rendered much faster. Bonus YES lol